# Set xlObj = CreateObject("excel.application") Requires Elevation (vbscript)

Tags: vbscript, elevation, requires, excel.application

Every time I try to run a script that includes the line Set xlObj = CreateObject("excel.application") in vbscript, I get an error saying "Line Requires Elevation".  I assume this is a permissions issue, but I'm an admin on the machine where I'm trying to run this script, so I'm not sure what I need to do about this.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 or higher? Have you tried running the script from an elevated command prompt? Right click on cmd.exe "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Does the error come from VBS\CScript.exe or from Excel? By default the built-in administrator does not get hassled by UAC. If you are an admin by virtue of being a member of the Local Administrators group then you will need to negotiate UAC. UAC kicks in when you attempt to create a process. If you can't disable UAC or run your script from a pre-elevated prompt. However Excel does not normally require elevation as it doesn't require access to system resources. Check whether Excel is trying to run a VBA macro which may need to be elevated.

Comment: I wonder if someone has set compatability on Excel to Run As Admin. Find the exe, not a shortcut, and check (right click - Properties - Compatability tab). Also check COM security. Look up `HKCR\Excel.Application`. Read the `ClassID` and look up `HKCR\CLSID\<the class id>`. Get the `AppID` and look up `HKCR\AppID\<the app id>`. On Office XP you'll get to `HKCR\AppID\{00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` which by default only has the display name of Excel.

Comment: AccessPermission, ActivateAtStorage, AppID, AuthenticationLevel, DllSurrogate, DllSurrogateExecutable, Endpoints, LaunchPermission, LocalService, RemoteServerName, RunAs, ServiceParameters, SRPTrustLevel are the possible settings.

Comment: I'm running on Windows 7, I've got Excel set to run as an admin; I'm not the owner of the machine, but I'm included as an admin.  The error comes from VBS, which spits out an error about wanting elevation before even loading Excel.

Comment: Shift + Right Click your script and choose Copy As Path. Right click a command prompt shortcut and choose Run As Administrator. In that window right click and choose Paste. Does your script work?

Comment: What is err.number and err.source.

Comment: For some reason, taking Excel off admin mode seems to work.  Why it works in normal mode but not in admin mode is a mystery to me, I must say.  Maybe the prompt blocks the script?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mystery about it. We told you and you said "No that can't be it". If set to admin then a non admin can't access it.