# how to automate the DCOM configuration settings (com security access permission settings)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, wmi, dcom

how to automate the access permission settings for the below manual settings of the 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633148.aspx

1. From the Start menu, click Run and type Dcomcnfg.exe.
2. In Component Services, click Console root, expand Component Services, expand Computers, and then click My Computer. On the Action menu, click Properties.
3. In the My Computer Properties dialog box, on the COM Security tab, in the Launch and Activation Permissions section, click Edit Limits.
4. In the Launch Permissions dialog box, click Add.
5. In the Select User, Computers, or Groups dialog box, in the Enter the object names to select (examples): box, type SMS Admins and click OK.
6. In the Permissions for SMS Admins section, select the check box to allow Remote Activation.
7. Click OK twice, and then close Computer Management.

Comment: If the end result of these steps is that they just update some settings in the registry, it may be easier to identify those changes and write them instead.

Comment: See how this stuff is stored http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982347/set-xlobj-createobjectexcel-application-requires-elevation-vbscript

Comment: anyone have idea win32_securitydescriptor,win32_trustee and win32_ace to this problem